# Unexpected viewport media query behaviour

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Tablet query runs normally:
`@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1250px)`
Mobile query runs as if it were the measurements of the tablet:
`@media screen and (max-width: 426px)`

```css
@media screen and (max-width:426px) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1250px) {
  body {
    background: url("img/backgournd_tablet.svg");
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1250px) and (max-width: 2040px) {
  body {
    background: url("img/background1.svg");
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0px;
  }
}
```

Note: I just set the background to green to see if it worked but nothing changes when I encode in mobile resolution.

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question. It is currently far too generic. See [ask] for tips, the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". A generic question followed by some tags is not sufficient.

Comment: Your code works fine for viewports up to 426px. Nothing happens between there and 768px (and what happens for very wide screens?). How are you testing your code because I don't think it has a problem (apart from your styling completely ignoring some viewport widths!).